# Getting Quality Gate issue while removing an item from a list in Apex

Tags: apex

Im simply removing an item using list.remove(index) method. Im getting a quality gate issue which says Im doing an operation on an immutable string. I cant understand the issue. Please help

```
 // wrapper class
    public class FilterList {

        @AuraEnabled
        public String[] division {get;set;}
        @AuraEnabled
        public String[] state {get;set;}
    

    }


 @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<DelegatedAccount> fetchAccountsOnLoad(FilterList filterList){
        String[] division, state;
 if(filterList != null && !filterList.division.isEmpty()){
                division = filterList.division;
                if(division.contains(MCX_GlobalConstants.nalcoWater)){
                    division.remove(MCX_GlobalConstants.nalcoWater);
                    division.add(MCX_GlobalConstants.WATER);
                    division.add(MCX_GlobalConstants.ENERGY);
                    division.add(MCX_GlobalConstants.PAPER);
                }
```

Here MCX_GlobalConstants is a constant class and those are public static final strings
Attached picture of issue
[image]

Comment: Looks like a false positive to me. Whatever this tool is doesn't seem to understand that `String[]` is a collection instead of a single string. If you can't live with that, then perhaps changing your string lists to `List<String>` might get it to stop complaining.

Comment: Yes this worked. Thanks !  the tool was CodeScan.io

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a false positive.

Your scanning tool (codescan.io, from the comments) appears to not know that `String[]` is a `List<String>` instead of a plain 'ol `String`. Bit of an oversight in a tool that specifically markets itself as being for Salesforce if you ask me, but then again I'm not an expert in automating static analysis.

If you don't have any internal controls that require the report from this tool to come back clean, then this report could be ignored.

If you do need a clean report, then using the (only slightly) longer form `List<String>` should make it abundantly clear that you're working on a (very mutable) list.